# NumPy Histogram - ValueError range parameter must be finite - input array is okay

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, histogram, valueerror

I'm struggling to understand this error, since I'll give you an example that's working and the one I'm interested in that's *not*.

I have to analyse a set of data with hourly prices for an entire year in it, called `sys_prices`, which - after various transformations - is a `numpy.ndarray` object with 8785 rows (1 column), and every row is a `numpy.ndarray` item with only one element, a `numpy.float64` number.

The code **not** working is the following:

```
stop_day = 95
start_day = stop_day - 10 # 10 days before
stop_day = (stop_day-1)*24
start_day = (start_day-1)*24

pcs=[] # list of prices to analyse
for ii in range(start_day, stop_day):
    pcs.append(sys_prices[ii][0])

p, x = np.histogram(pcs, bins='fd')
```

The `*24` part is to tune the index within the dataset so that to respect the hourly resolution.

What I expect is to supply the list `pcs` to the *histogram* method, so that to get the values of my histogram and bin edges into *p* and *x*, respectively.

I say that I expect this because the following code **works**:

```
start_day = 1 
start_month = 1 
start_year = 2016 
stop_day = 1
stop_month = 2 
stop_year = 2016
num_prices = (date(stop_year, stop_month, stop_day) - date(start_year, start_month, start_day)).days*24

jan_prices = []
for ii in range(num_prices):
    jan_prices.append(sys_prices[ii][0])

p, x = np.histogram(jan_prices, bins='fd') # bin the data`
```

The difference in the codes is that the working one is analyzing only 10 days within an arbitrary period starting backwards from a chosen day of the year, while the working example uses all the prices in the month of January (eg. the first 744 values of the dataset).

**Strange(r) thing:** I used different values for `stop_day`, and it seems that 95 raises the error, while 99 or 100 or 200 *don't*.

Could you help me?

Comment: Show us the exact, complete error message, including stack trace.

Comment: It sounds like your input has infinite or NaN values in it.

Comment: @user2357112 yes, this is what it sounds. But I don't understand why the same dataset, sliced differently, sometimes it produces that error and sometimes not.

The full error is: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-ec3777e6831e>", line 11, in <module>
    p, x = np.histogram(pcs, bins='fd') # bin the data

  File "C:\Users\Filippo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 669, in histogram
    'range parameter must be finite.')

ValueError: range parameter must be finite.`

Comment: I entered the `function_base` to understand it, and it seems like some _minimum_ and _maximum_ variables are infinite of NaN.

Considering the dataset is full of float numbers, and some of them have periodic numbers in their decimals, could that be the case? 

I have applied the `float` method to the numbers when appending them into the list: would that solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because, by default, histogram uses min(pcs) and max(pcs) to determine the minimum and maximum range of the bins but since you have nans in your dataset the min and max becomes nans. You can fix this by using `np.nanmin` and `np.nanmax` for the range parameters.

`p, x = np.histogram(pcs, range=(np.nanmin(pcs), np.nanmax(pcs)) bins='fd')`

I think this is better than accepted answer since it does not require modifying of pcs.

Comment: Hello @kkawabat, thank you for your answer!

Looking back at the previous solution, that was a 'fix' that couldn't work. Your solution, instead, is practical and error-proof.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it, there was a single NaN in the dataset I couldn't spot.

For those wondering how to spot it, I just used this code to find the index of the item:

```
nanlist=[]
for ii in range(len(array)):
    if numpy.isnan(array[ii]):
        nanlist.append(ii)
```

Where `array` is your container.

Comment: Note that you can do that loop as `np.argwhere(np.isnan(array)))`.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks, I didn't know that method! It should be faster, right?

Comment: More importantly it works on arrays with more than one dimension.